# AngularJS scope variable for object in filter

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I'm trying to change which property I'm filtering by assigning the property name to a variable, but it's not working. Is there a way to accomplish this without writing my own filter? [codepen](http://codepen.io/alex-wilmer/pen/gbWqYN?editors=101)

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="main as m">
  <input ng-model="keyword"/>
  <p>Property: {{m.property}}</p> <!-- resolves to 'name' -->
  <!-- does not work-->
  <div ng-repeat="o in m.objects | filter:{m.property:keyword}">
    {{o.name}}
  </div>
  <hr/>
  <!-- works-->
  <div ng-repeat="o in m.objects | filter:{name:keyword}">
    {{o.name}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your question right, I think [this](http://plnkr.co/edit/07Dyd6pEX5RIPUDmph0p?p=preview) is what you are looking for.

Relevant code:

HTML:

```
<select ng-model="property" ng-change="clearSearch()">
  <option>name</option>
  <option>age</option>
  <option>city</option>
</select>

<input ng-model="search[property]" />

<div class="box">
  <div class="item" ng-repeat="item in data | filter:search">
    {{item.name}} | {{item.age}} | {{item.city}}
  </div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
var app = angular.module("myapp", []);
app.controller("main", function($scope){
  $scope.search = {};
  $scope.clearSearch = function(){
    $scope.search.name = "";
    $scope.search.age = "";
    $scope.search.city = "";
  }
  $scope.property = "name";
  $scope.data = [
      {
        name: "Robert",
        age: 23,
        city: "Orem"
      },
      {
        name: "Alice",
        age: 44,
        city: "Nephi"
      },
      {
        name: "Susan",
        age: 12,
        city: "Odgen"
      },
      {
        name: "Henry",
        age: 63,
        city: "South Jordan"
      },
      {
        name: "Frank",
        age: 35,
        city: "Provo"
      },
      {
        name: "Albert",
        age: 32,
        city: "Payson"
      },
  ];
});
```

Comment: Perfect! You're a boss =D

Answer (score 1):

In short, `<div ng-repeat="o in m.objects | filter:{m.property:keyword}">`  {m.property:keyword} is not a correct [expression](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/expression)

Comment: I gathered that, `filter:{name:keyword}` IS a proper expression, so I'm wondering how I achieve what the code looks like it would expect to achieve. Since `m.property == 'name'`, It seems like it would work.

Comment: because m.property == 'name' is a correct expression. You should read the ref link I just added

Comment: That doesn't answer my question still... I'm not asking how to create proper expressions, I'm asking how to filter objects by a variable property name using angular's out of box `filter`

Comment: Also I should note, that it IS a valid expression, as invalid expressions throw a syntax error in the console.

Comment: Ah... What I am trying to say is it doesn't work as you expected. It doesn't interpret m.property

Comment: Hence why I asked the question on stackoverflow. I guess I'll just write my own filter then..

Comment: You may not be asking how to create proper expressions, but often times reading ancillary material can provide the necessary insight into why your code isn't working.  Be careful not to brush aside links like @maxisam's to quickly, especially when they come from an experienced developer (he's got nearly 10,000 points after all); I've solved many programming problems by reading what seemed initially like irrelevant information.

Comment: Expression is somehow like Javascript. You don't expect to create an object like  {m.property:keyword}

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried filter without the "m." in "m.property"?

```
<div ng-repeat="o in m.objects | filter:{property:keyword}">
```

Comment: No that doesn't work as well, it doesn't matter if I'm using `ng-controller='ctrlName as name'` syntax or `$scope` syntax, trying to use a scope variable for the property to filter on doesn't work.